# what's technology is used for the user interface of gyrex admin web application

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, web, osgi

I am trying to learn osgi these days. I download a OSGi based server [gyrex](http://www.eclipse.org/gyrex/). I found the user interface of it's admin application is quite rich. I want to know what technology was used to build this web application. HTML+Javascript? or JSF? or Eclipse RAP or something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be RAP 2.0.

GIT repository is here: https://github.com/eclipse/gyrex-admin .

As you can see, no HTML/JS/CSS in the source tree and several mentions of RAP 2.0 instead.

Comment: Yes. It's RAP. We recently removed the "workbench" stuff and use plain SWT APIs to build the web UI. RAP renders it into HTML and JavaScript. It's not as flexible as a pure HTML/JavaScript UI (there are some limitations) but most of our developers have an SWT background which makes it so convenient for us. :)

Comment: WFIW, the backend has been merged into the main Git repository.
http://git.eclipse.org/c/gyrex/gyrex-server.git/tree/admin